# evenDigits in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Write a method evenDigits that accepts an integer parameter n and that returns the integer formed by removing the odd digits from n. The following table shows several calls and their expected return values:
If a negative number with even digits other than 0 is passed to the method, the result should also be negative, as shown above when -34512 is passed. Leading zeros in the result should be ignored and if there are no even digits other than 0 in the number, the method should return 0, as shown in the last three outputs.
Sample calls: evenDigits(8342116) Value returned: 8426
evenDigits(35179) Value returned: 0
evenDigits(-163505) Value returned: -60

```
public int evenDigits(int n){
    int result = 0;
    int a = n%10;
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(a%2==0){
        result = a + 10*evenDigits(n/10);
    } else {
        result = evenDigits(n/10);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I came up with the solution but I was getting a number format error exception if I remove the this if statement at the starting which is

```
if(n==0){
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain me what is the purpose of that if statement, I am confused about it. What exactly is that doing ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if (n == 0)` *blocks* the otherwise infinite recursion: notice how in all other cases, `evenDigits` is called yet again.

Once `n` is zero, the job is done, and all the calling stacks can unwind. See for yourself with your favourite debugger.